# Retrieve number of factor levels from columns within a function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function that performs several statistical tests on specific columns in a dataframe. Some of the tests require more than one level. I would like to test how many levels are in a specific column, but can't seem to get it right.

In my actual code this section would be followed by an ifelse that returns a string saying 'only one level' if single, or continues to the statistical test if > 1.

```
require("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c("a", "a", "a"), C = c("a", "b", "b")) %>%
    mutate(A = factor(A)) %>%
    mutate(B = factor(B)) %>%
    mutate(C = factor(C))

my_funct <- function(data_f, column){

    n_fact <- paste("data_f", column, sep = "$")

    n_levels <- do.call("nlevels",
                        list(x = as.name(n_fact)))
    print(n_levels)
}
```

```

Then I call my function with the dataframe and column

```
my_funct(df, "A")
```

I get the following error:
Error in levels(x) : object 'data_f$A' not found

If I remove the as.name() wrapper it returns a value of 0.

Comment: `nlevels(df[,match(column, names(df))])`

Comment: Perfect. Guess I was over-complicating.  Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't I only use data_f and not df from within the function so I am only relying on arguments defined within the context of the function? Or does that not matter.

Comment: Yes, just use `data_f` inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason your code is not working is because `data_f$A` is not the name of any object available to the function.

But I would recommend you don't even try to parse code as strings.  It's the wrong way to do it.  All you need is double bracket indexing `[[`.  So the body of your function can be the following single line:

```
nlevels(data_f[[column]])
```

And for all the columns:

```
sapply(data_f, nlevels)
```